# Activiate jQuery function based on radio button selection w/o using .change

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

When my ASP MVC 3 page loads, the user may or may not have a value selected from a group of radio buttons. If, when the page loads, a value is selected (before the user clicks on a button), how would i activate a jquery function?

Currently I use a `.change()` method to activate some code which decides what menu to display:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function () {
        //Clear out values
        $('input:text').val('');
        $('input:text').text('');

        //Display input fields
        var radioValue = $(this);

        $('#RightDiv').children().each(function () {
            if (radioValue.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id')) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work :

```
$('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function () {
     //Your code
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

I am asuming the input are checkbox's, if that's not the case, you can remove the `.filter()`.

Trigger doc : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: For some reason this seems to make the code execute once for every radio button selection and always settles on the last one.

Comment: @NealR, i'll asume your input are checkbox or radio, see my edited answer.